# Can't Start Tomcat server from Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed Apache Tomcat in my computer. I added the server in Netbeans but I can't start it because the start button is disabled. See Screenshot

[image]

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: Is Tomcat already running? If you click on the "Stop" menu item (in your screenshot), does the "Start" option then become available?

Comment: it is not running. I also have an authentification problem. I introduce the user and password that are defined in tomcat-users.xml and they are not accepted

Comment: OK, understood - it's just that in your screenshot, the "start" option is disabled (grey), but the "stop" option is enabled (black)... That only happens (in my experience) if NetBeans thinks Tomcat is already running.

Comment: There are some difficulties with Netbeans 12 and Tomcat plugin, unclear for me. Version 11 works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the start search Services>Apache Tomcat9.0 > right click > properties >startup type >select[image] Manual> and stop the server there